# Missing tf after compile ROS for Cross-compile ROS for the NAO

Tags: ros, cross-compiling, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

does anyone come acroos the error when proceed to the stage 6 for cross-compile ROS for the NAO. the error message is roscd: No such package 'tf'.  (http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling   -> stage 6. installing TF)
I am configuring with electric ros  and Aldebaran sdk 1.12.3 on Oneiric 11.10
can I just copy the tf package from my ROS master installed in my computer?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39587/missing-tf-after-compile-ros-for-cross-compile-ros-for-the-nao/) by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-07-23**:
Please link to the instructions you are following.

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2012-07-29**:
The linkhttp://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling -> stage 6. installing TF  ( tf directory and bullet are not installed) I install the ROS-Full ( http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling). Thanks in advance

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2012-07-31**:
I am desperate. I tried to reinstall with a new environment, Natty 10.04 and Aldebaran sdk 1.10.53 and electric ros ( ros-full  -- "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=ros-full&overlay=no"), but still the same error. Missing tf. need help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally..I got it :)

---

Originally posted by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) with karma: 128 on 2012-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0